# Devowelling an input using getchar() in C

Tags: c, loops, character, getchar

Having a bit of trouble, and am confused as to why this wont work. The code will take the input and print the input without any lower case vowels.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    int i=getchar();
        while (i != EOF) {
            if(i!='a' && i!='e' && i!='i'&&i!='o' && i!='u') {
                printf("%c", i);
                i=getchar();    
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Looks like your second call to `getchar()` needs to be outside the `if` statement.

Comment: Bug reports should have three things. (1) Smallest code sample exhibiting the problem. Check. (2) What you expect to happen. Check. (3) What *actually* happens. Missing.

Comment: I believe the technical term is "disemvowelling".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `if` statement.

If the input character is not in {a,e,i,o,u} then you print the character and get a new character. But you really want to get a new character every time through the loop. Since `i` isn't changing when it's a vowel, the code runs forever -- never reaching `EOF`.

The fix is to move the call to `getchar()` to just after the `if` statement.